# Are there any events that can be missed in The Longing?

Tags: the-longing

Once started, time keeps on running in The Longing even while the game is not running. Are there any events that can accidentally be missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two events that can actually be missed but you do not need to be afraid of it because ...

> there is a way to go back in time.

They are :

> Shade birthday (365 days after the start). A special event happens in one of the cave which is key to one of the endings.

> Old man death. On the overworld there is an old man that periodically use the well. One of the endings is linked to him.

Comment: Great, thanks! Having found some water I was afraid the caves would flood at some point or such.